# How to align an image in Qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, image, layout, alignment, qooxdoo

I'm currently creating a new Qooxdoo application, and have setup a layout similar to the Feedreader demo, with a banner image across the top (logo etc). I've had no problem adding the image into the javascript but cant for the life of me find a way to have it right-aligned on the screen. I've tried using various layout options, vbox, hbox, atom etc but no joy.

Unfortunately because of the perl-based compiler I've been developing this on my laptop at home rather than on the web server so I can't paste in my code at this time.

Any ideas?

If not, I'll post the code later on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try a simple canvas layout and align the logo on the right? Just check out the playground sample over here: http://tinyurl.com/cuufhmh